# Converting YYYYMM to the last weekday or business day of the month

Tags: r, date, zoo

I have a date in YYYYMM format i.e.

```
d <- "202003"
```

I'd like to make this a date object, and using `as.yearmon` from `zoo` and a trick from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/141796.html

```
lastday <- as.Date(as.yearmon(d, "%Y%m"), frac = 1)
```

But this gives me the last *calendar* day of the month. How can I get the last *business* day or *weekday* of the month?

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 1 day if the lastday is Saturday and 2 days if Sunday.  Formatting with %u will give 6 for Saturday and 7 for Sunday so subtract 5 from that and 0 it out if it is negative.

```
lastday - pmax(as.numeric(format(lastday, "%u")) - 5, 0)
```